# minidom doesn't read \\n newline character at the end of line

Tags: python, xml, newline, minidom

I am using minidom parser to read the xml. The problem I am facing is that it is not reading end of line character when it is done reading the line. For example my xml file is something like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><ItemGroup>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">setlocal
C:\Tools\CMake2.8\bin\cmake.exe C:/tb/Source/../</Command>
</ItemGroup>
```

and my python code looks something like :

```
dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse(fileFullPath)
nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName('Command')
for j in range(len(nodes)):#{
  path = nodes[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue
  if nodeName == 'Command':#{
    pathList = path.split(' ')
    for i in range(len(pathList)):#{
      sPath = pathList[i]
      if sPath.find('\\n')!=-1:
        print 'sPath has \\n'
    #}
  #}
#}
```

(Please ignore/point out any indentation errors)

 now even though `setlocal` and `C:\Tools\CMake2.8\bin\cmake.exe` have a newline character in between them in the xml file, my code is not able to read it and I don't know why. Can somebody help ?

update :
I am trying to split the `<Command>` into ['setlocal', 'C:\Tools\CMake2.8\bin\cmake.exe', 'C:/tb/Source/../']

Comment: How are you trying to handle the text within a `<Command>`? The first line in it is `setlocal` and the second is `C:\Tools\CMake2.8\bin\cmake.exe C:/tb/Source/../`. Or a better way to put it is: what do you want the result to look like after you've parsed the text from `<Command>`?

Comment: Are you trying to split `<Command>` into `['setlocal', 'C:\\Tools\\CMake2.8\bin\\cmake.exe', 'C:/tb/Source/../']`?

Comment: yes. I am trying to split the <Command> into ['setlocal', 'C:\\Tools\\CMake2.8\bin\\cmake.exe', 'C:/tb/Source/../']

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting the text value on a space (`' '`), you want to split it on all white space and since these look like command lines, they should be split using a proper parser. You want to change:

```
pathList = path.split(' ')
for i in range(len(pathList)):#{
  sPath = pathList[i]
  if sPath.find('\\n')!=-1:
    print 'sPath has \\n'
```

To:

```
import shlex
pathList = shlex.split(path, posix=False)
```

This will give you:

```
['setlocal', 'C:\\Tools\\CMake2.8\\bin\\cmake.exe', 'C:/tb/Source/../']
```

- NOTE: If any of your paths contain spaces and are not properly quoted, they will be split incorrectly. E.g., `'C:\\Program Files'` would be split to `['C:\\Program', 'Files']` but `'"C:\\Program Files"'` will be split to `['C:\\Program Files']`.

---

Also, your code could use a little cleaning because Python is not C,
Javascript, etc.

```
import xml.dom.minidom
import shlex

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse(fileFullPath)
nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName('Command')
for node in nodes:
  path = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue
  pathList = shlex.split(path, posix=False)
  print pathList
```

Comment: I am using indices because I want to traverse the lists sequentially. Also checking for '\n' too doesn't work in my case. I have tried that already. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, considering line separators independently of 
the particular OS, might be the following, using the `in` operator
and `os.linesep`. I also tried this code using `'\n'` (without escaping
the backslash) instead of `os.linesep`. Both versions worked.
(My shell didn't take running `xml.dom.minidom.parse(...)`, therefore 
there are some changes in the imports you may ignore.)

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import os

dom = parse(fileFullPath)
nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName('Command')

for node in nodes:
    path = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue
    if node.nodeName == 'Command':
        for path in path.split(' '):
            if os.linesep in path:
                print r'Path contains \n or whatever your OS uses.'
```

I also left `' '` inside the split, as it seems that having `setlocal` in your list of paths
is not your aim.

EDIT: 
After I noticed your comment stating that you actually *want* to have `setlocal` in your
list, I would also say that checking for `\n` is redundant, because splitting
by all whitespaces of course also considers line separators as whitespaces.

```
'a\nb'.split()
```

gives

```
['a', 'b']
```